# Mount a file/folder as a removable drive

Tags: windows-7, mount, removable-media, subst

I'm trying to test an application I've written to image USB drives when they're plugged in. Unfortunately, I've just lent my last one to a friend.

I know I can mount a folder as a drive using `subst` but a) that appears as a fixed disk and b) the size information is invalid.

Things that I can't do in my app while using subst:

- Check the drive type != fixed
- Check the drive capacity is < 32GB
- Format the drive before I start copying files

Two of those are fairly important sanity checks and the last is an important step I'd like to test properly.

I intend to get some more usb sticks in the next couple of days but there must be some technique out there that will let me mount a file as a removable drive? At the very least, can I convince subst to present the drive as if it were removable?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive

Comment: I'm aware of RAM disks. In fact, I used them back in the day under MSDOS :) But I haven't found any way to mount one that doesn't present as a fixed disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of hunting around, it turns out that TrueCrypt has the ability to mount an encrypted volume as a removable drive. Unfortunately, since it's discontinued, the latest version can't create new volumes. GRC have [mirrored a copy of 7.1a](https://www.grc.com/misc/truecrypt/truecrypt.htm) which does support volume creation.

The option to mount as removable media is under Settings->Preferences